# How to save Log message to a string in android?

Tags: android

Is there any way that I could directly redirect the log message in Android to a string?

For example, I have a log message in Android.

```
Log.v(TAG, "First Name" + firstName);

Log.v(TAG, "Last Name"  +  lastName);
```

I have a string

```
String nameMessage = "Please check your credetials\n" ;
```

I want to concatenate the log to the message.

One way is to concatenate manually.
I am looking If we could redirect the log to message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I am understanding your question right, but technically you could just create a function that appends the log message and then actually logs it?

Example:

```
private StringBuilder errorMessage;

public void log(String tag, String message) {
    errorMessage.append(message).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    Log.v(tag, message);
}

public void getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage.toString();
}
```

And then, you'd just replace all your calls to Log#v with a call to #log(tag, message).